# Display the number of rows generated by an ngFor* Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a component which displays the results of a search. It's a list of table, where each table is the percentage of elements contained in a chemical analysis for a series (it has a unique ID). I want to display the number of series at the top of my component  i.e. the number of elements in array *keys*

**element.component.html:**

```
    <ul class="cert-result">
      <li *ngFor="let key of objectKey(formatedCerts())">
        <div class="serie-header">
          <span>Series: {{key}}</span>
        </div>
        <table class="cert-table">
          <tr>
            <th>Element</th>
            <th>Value</th>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let certificate of formatedCerts()[key]">
            <td>{{certificate.ident}}</td>
            <td>{{certificate.moy_certifiee}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

**element.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, SimpleChange } from '@angular/core';

import { ElementFilter } from '../element-filter';
import { MrcCertService } from '../mrc-cert.service';
import { Element } from '../element';
import { IElement } from '../element.interface';
import { Certificate } from '../certificate';
import { forEach } from '@angular/router/src/utils/collection';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-elements',
  templateUrl: './elements.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./elements.component.css']
})

export class ElementsComponent implements OnInit {
  filters: ElementFilter[];
  elements: Element[];
  criteria: ElementFilter;
  certificates: Certificate[];

  constructor(private mrcService: MrcCertService) {
    this.filters = new Array<ElementFilter>();
    this.elements = new Array<Element>(); }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mrcService.getElements()
      .subscribe(element => { element.forEach(item => {
          this.elements.push(new Element(item.Ident, item.Description));
        });
    });
  }

  objectKey(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj);
  }

  formatedCerts() {
    return this.certificates.reduce(
      (prev, now) => {
        if (!prev[now.serie]) {
          prev[now.serie] = [];
        }
        prev[now.serie].push(now);
        return prev;
      }, {}
    );
  }

  /** some other functions ...*/
}
```

**element.ts**

```
export class Element {
    ident: string;
    description: string;

    constructor(ident: string, description: string) {
        this.ident = ident;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

**certificate.ts**

```
export class Certificate {
    serie: string;
    ident: string;
    moy_certifiee: string;
    seq: string;

    constructor(serie: string, ident: string, moy_certifiee: string, seq: string) {
        this.serie = serie;
        this.ident = ident;
        this.moy_certifiee = moy_certifiee;
        this.seq = seq;
    }
}
```

**Wanted**

```
Result(s): 3
--------------------
  Series: A
    Si: 1%
    Zr: 3%

  Series: B
    Ag: 3%
    Be: 6%

  Series: C
    Be: 3%
    Xe:4%
```

My attempts at this were unsuccessful since this number is outside my *ngFor. How could I achieve this with Angular 6 ? Being new to Angular, this pose a challenge to my understanding and I could not find an answer from the official docs or from Google.

Comment: What's your code look like? I'm pretty sure you can just call `{{ results.length }}`

Comment: Can you console log and post the data here

Comment: I have put my real code instead in my original post.

Comment: what is `formatedCerts`? your `component ` and `html` are different?

Comment: you can take `{{keys.length}}`

Comment: The number of items should be outside my list since it is the total of items (results). This number of results will not be repeated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `resultCount: number;` to ElementsComponent class

Amend objectKey method to:

```
 objectKey(obj) {
var result = Object.keys(obj);
this.resultCount = result.length;
    return result;
  }
```

Now you can use count anywhere you want in html by using `{{resultsCount}}`

Comment: It works as expecetd. I just forgot that you could have access to a variable everywhere in you component with {{foo.bar}} without the need to be inside a repeater directive.